# How to validate method bytes using respondsToSelector for value from HomeKit in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, homekit

Below is the code which i am tying to convert into Swift 4,
i could see respondsToSelector: is not available in Swift 4

**Below is the Objective-c code which is working perfectly:**

```
-(id)getValueFromHomeKitValue:(id)homeKitValue{
 if ( [homeKitValue respondsToSelector:@selector(bytes)] ){
       NSData * data = (NSData *) homeKitValue;
       uint64_t value = *(uint8_t*)[homeKitValue bytes];
       return value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  func getValueFromHomeKitValue(_ homeKitValue: Any?) -> Any? {
    if homeKitValue?.responds(to: #selector(self.bytes)) ?? false {
      let data = homeKitValue as? Data
      return UInt8(homeKitValue?.bytes())
    }
  }
```

Comment: i believe value of type 'Any' has no member 'responds' in swift 4. tried with your solution trowing error

Comment: can you please explain your use case I will try to do it accordingly

Comment: I will get value from HomeKit delegate while HomeKit pairing . 1. need to check that value has bytes method 2.if so convert to Data type and assign to uint64_t value = *(uint8_t*)[homeKitValue bytes];

Comment: conversion from bytes to UInt64 is different in Swift4, which i am not able to achive